# Convert unicode array to UTF-8 php

Tags: php, arrays, unicode, utf-8, telegram-bot

*This is my code:*

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BachWpLgFAp/';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode( 'edge_media_to_caption": {"edges": [{"node": {"text": "' , $content );
$second_step = explode("}}]}" , $first_step[1] );

$str = $second_step[0];
$str2 = substr($str, 0, -1);
print_r ($str2);

$caption = $str2;
if($user_message == "/test"){

            var_dump(bot('sendMessage',[
        'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
        'text'=>$caption,

    ]));
}

?>
```

**Output data of $caption is:**  You\u2019re never too old to play in the mud. #teampixel photographer @samarthv.pattar throws a \u270c\ufe0f sign at his reflection after the rain.

How i can convert \u codes to utf-8?

Comment: As far as I can see, all of this code is irrelevant to the question, which could actually be worded as "I have a string like `...throws a \u270c\ufe0f sign at his reflection...` and need to convert the `\u` escapes into UTF-8."

Comment: use [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: are you splitting a json-string manually? Why don't you just `json_decode` it??

Comment: @Gajanan Kulkarni . My code gives caption from Instagram posts, But come character in output is unicode and i want be utf-8

Comment: @Jeff Where use? When i use json_decode($str2); there isn't output.

Comment: use it where you wanna convert it. `$caption=mb_convert_encoding($str2,'UTF-8');`

Comment: @Jeff I try mb_convert_encoding 
but output data have not any changes. :(

Comment: @TomUdding Thanks, It works ;)

Answer (score 2):

This seems a little but dumb to me. You shouldn't try to parse the json string on your own. Why not just extract the whole json string and then use `json_decode`.

```
$url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BachWpLgFAp/';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
if (preg_match('/<script[^>]+>\s*window\._sharedData[^\{]+(\{.*?);\s*<\/script>/ms', $content, $m)) {
    $json = $m[1];
    $jsonData = json_decode($json, true);
}
```

After getting the jsonData, you could such search in the given array for edge_media_to_caption.

```
foreach ($jsonData['entry_data']['PostPage'] as $page) {
    $graphql = $page['graphql'];
    var_dump($graphql['shortcode_media']['edge_media_to_caption']);
}
```

Btw. there's an official Instagram Api, which should be the official way to get your desired information. https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/
What you are currently doing might be against their terms of usage.

Comment: it have error in  $json = $m[1];

Error: Syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: add an `)` to the if condition before `{`

Comment: Unicode characters have a bad habit of making json_encode drop dead. That's what brought me here.